# background-image is not showing in dompdf laravel

Tags: laravel, background-image

controller.php

```
use PDF;
use Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF;

use Dompdf\Exception;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

   public function pdf()
    { 

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('Donor.certificate');
        return  $pdf->download('certificate.pdf');

    }
```

blade.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PDF Upn</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        * {
        font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
        font-size: 8px;
        }
        .upn {
        background-image:url('../img/certificate_template.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:100%;
        height:100vh;
        background-size: cover;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="upn">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <img src="../img/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

composer.json

```
 "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
    },
```

problem is that background-image is not showing in pdf but test word is written ...if i use tag img inside the dive then its works fine...i want to display background-image and want to code on that image but its not showing what is which i am missing ,anyone can check this code please.

Comment: Have you checked your image path correctly?

Comment: Pls. try changing your path with this background-image:url('../../../img/certificate_template.png');

Comment: Now Image is showing in pdf but DOMPDF Background image Displaying Incorrect Size? why?

Answer (score 0):

for your template png specify the location of image

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=utf-8" />
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>PDF Upn</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            * {
            font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
            font-size: 8px;
            }
            .upn {
            background-image:url('/img/certificate_template.png');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            background-size: cover;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="upn">
                <h1>test</h1>
                <img src="{{url('/')}}/img/logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: working fine for me now thanks...i also use {{url('/')}} in background-image url......then its working fine.....but now its raise one problem....DOMPDF Background image Displaying Incorrect Size? why?

Comment: set width="" height=""  in img src

Comment: i am facing problem in background-image not  image src so how to manage that size to display correct in pdf...but in document view its view is correct .